# Turn image URL into the image after parsing JSon using Rails

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My question is how do I render the image itself instead of the image url when I am parsing a JSON using HTTParty on Rails.  I am able to render the image_url as it comes through but would like the image there instead?  For example, instead of seeing:
"image_url":"https://d2eyrv63e6x6lp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/20141833/John-Smith.jpg"

I would like to see the actual image that this represents.

I'm using HTTParty to parse the JSon on Ruby on Rails 5.

Here is my current view:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Bio</th>
      <th>Vote</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @rosters.each do |roster| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= roster['name'] %></td>
        <td><%= roster['image_url'] %></td>
        <td><%= roster['title'] %></td>
        <td><%= roster['bio'] %></td>
        <td><%= roster['vote'] %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Current Controller:

```
def index
    @rosters = HTTParty.get('https://api.example', :headers =>{'Content_Type' => 'application/json'})
end
```

Current Model:

```
class Roster < ApplicationRecord

include HTTParty
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`image_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helper

So in your case:

```
<td><%= image_tag(roster['image_url']) %></td>
```

Should do the trick

Comment: How do we add a class to resize the image?

Comment: @Sohel did you follow the link provided? it is fairly explanatory on this subject.